# Firefox history viewer won't show pages without a name?

Tags: firefox, history

The history viewer won't show pages which don't have a name, but the address bar is showing them (it just shows the url) I need to delete them though, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In firefox, control shift delete will delete your recent history. You will be given a screen where you can choose from what time perido and what elements to clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to type the URL into the history sidebar (`CTRL+H`) or library search (`Firefox button -> History -> Show all History -> Search bar`) and it should appear. Then you can right-click the entry and Delete as normal.